# Get survey questions via Rest API

Tags: survey-list, survey, odata, rest

I am able to get all the fields in a survey using the web api url :

> _api/Web/Lists(guid'cecxc8b4-bbvc-472c-ae3f-d648bd0bb025')/Fields

How ever I am not able to distinguish questions from the fields. It is returning all the fields (internal, hidden etc.).

Is there a way to get the questions only? Will an Odata filter work?

I need to render these questions in client side using angularJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also filter fields by [SPField.CanBeDeleted property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.canbedeleted.aspx) in order to get the list of questions from a Survey List

How to get the list of questions from a Survey List via REST API

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Survey')/fields?$filter=(CanBeDeleted eq true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out a method. This might not be the optimised one.

We can use Odata filter to get only the questions of a survey.

> _api/Web/Lists(guid'cecxc8b4-bbvc-472c-ae3f-d648bd0bb025')/Fields?$filter=(Hidden
>   eq false) and (ReadOnlyField eq false) and (FromBaseType eq false)